# Sharing maven build across different projects in CircleCI

Tags: maven, github, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I have to 2 git repositories. Lets call them Project A and Project B. Both are java maven apps.
I am trying to setup CI/CD in CircleCi for both projects.

But build/targets from Project A are required as dependency in Project B.

How should I configure Project B in circleci so that is uses build from Project A.

In other words how can both Projects in circleci have same .m2 folder ?

Comment: If those builds should have the same `.m2` repository, you need to make sure that they never run at the same time. BTW, don't you have a Nexus or Artifactory to store your artifacts?

Comment: No they are private maven project

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to share maven builds across different projects in circleci.

What I did for my problem here is that I configured my GitHub Java maven project to build
and deploy as a [GitHub Packages](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages)

GitHub packages allow you to deploy your maven builds under the same GitHub Repository as a GitHub Package.

Later I configured my circleci's maven settings.xml to fetch builds from maven central and GitHub Packages.

This way my maven builds remain private and the packages/builds are shareable across different projects in circleci build.